# Keep zero values with GROUP BY and SUM in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, sum

I have two tables career_types and bookings

career_types

```
id | name
1 | foo
2 | bar
3 | baz
```

bookings

```
id | career_type_id | details
1 | 1 | foo
2 | 1 | bar
3 | 2 | baz
```

My bookings table has a lot of entries for all career types except career_types.id of 3.

I want a query that will list all my career_types.name's and how many each booking has, and in the case of career_types.id = 1 where there are no bookings for it. I want to return 0.

So far I've been trying variations of

```
SELECT career_types.name, sum(bookings.id)
FROM career_types
LEFT JOIN bookings ON (career_types.id = bookings.career_type_id)
GROUP BY career_types.id
```

And the result I'm looking for is

```
career_types.name | sum
foo | 2
bar | 1
baz | 0
```

But at the moment I'm not able to get any output for baz.

Comment: You should be using `COUNT` not `SUM`

Comment: I should change the above example, in my real world application the field in bookings could be any number. It's that number I need to sum

Comment: Yes the example is confusing in that regard. But your query looks fine otherwise.

Comment: Query works as expected http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/246144/1

Comment: it works http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/20585/0

Comment: Use proper `GROUP BY`.  `SELECT career_types.name`, but `GROUP BY career_types.id`.  That's an invalid query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate functions only include non-null values in their calculations. In the case of SUM, and most aggregate functions, the result is null if no non-null values are encountered. If zero is needed, rather than null, this can be accounted for simply with:
`IFNULL(SUM(x), 0)`