# How to keep 0 value entries when doing Count and GroupBy in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried `isnull` but it's still leaving out certain bins of data if the count in that bin is 0. I am using group by to count the number of observations in each group. For groups with 0 observations, SQL does not print out a row for that group. I want a row for that group and a corresponding 0 value.

I have tried this: [Keep zero values with GROUP BY and SUM in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52174105/keep-zero-values-with-group-by-and-sum-in-mysql)

Thanks!

Edit with data:

```
Vector = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 9, 10, 10]
```

I want to count the number of observations in the above that fall into the bins:

```
[1-2, 3-4, 5-6, 7-8, 9-10]
```

The results should be

```
[3,2,2,0,3]
```

However I get

```
[3,2,2,3]
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and the query that is producing your current results.

Comment: "I have tried is null ..."  Where???  We don't see any code!

Comment: Please read this to learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You could create "bin" derived table and LEFT JOIN to it:

```
SELECT bin.a, bin.b, COUNT(v.val) AS cnt
FROM (VALUES (1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8),(9,10)) bin(a,b)
LEFT JOIN vector v
  ON v.val BETWEEN bin.a AND bin.b
GROUP BY bin.a, bin.b
ORDER BY bin.a, bin.b;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d2a220020a493fbf197857bd424349f1)**

Output:

```
+----+-----+-----+
| a  | b   | cnt |
+----+-----+-----+
| 1  |  2  |   3 |
| 3  |  4  |   2 |
| 5  |  6  |   2 |
| 7  |  8  |   0 |
| 9  | 10  |   3 |
+----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach which creates the bins as separate columns.  Then the final string is created using CONCAT_WS and QUOTENAME.  Something like this

```
declare @Vector         varchar(max)='1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 9, 10, 10';

with
range_cte(n) as (
    select * from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) v(n))
select quotename(concat_ws(',',
       sum(case when sc.value in(1, 2) then 1 else 0 end) ,
       sum(case when sc.value in(3, 4) then 1 else 0 end) ,
       sum(case when sc.value in(5, 6) then 1 else 0 end) ,
       sum(case when sc.value in(7, 8) then 1 else 0 end) ,
       sum(case when sc.value in(9, 10) then 1 else 0 end)),'[]')
from range_cte rc 
     left join string_split(@Vector, ',') sc on rc.n=sc.value;
```

Output

```
[3,2,2,0,3]
```